# how to bind imageurl of datalist to the image control which is out side of datalist on insert command

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have a image coltrol out side of datalist, I want to assign the image url to this image control on insert command.

Data List:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" onitemcommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" CaptionAlign="Right" CellSpacing="6">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Controls/ShowImage.ashx?FileName=" +DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") %>'
 OnCommand="Insert_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id").ToString() +";"+Eval("FilePath")%>' />
 <asp:Label ID="lblimagenumber" runat ="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName") %>' ></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

image control out side the datalist:

```
<div id="loadarea" class="imageViewArea">
        <asp:Image ID="imgthumb" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

insert command:

```
protected void Insert_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] str = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
        hImgInsId.Value = str[0];
        ImgName = str[1];

        //Image imgThumb = (Image)this.FindControl("imgthumb");
        //imgThumb.ImageUrl=
        //how to assign datalist image url to image contol here...?
        // this is datalist imagebtn imageurl ImageUrl='<%#"~/Controls/ShowImage.ashx?FileName=" +DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") %>'
    }

   public void BindImages()
    {
        List<int> ImgIds = new List<int>();
        List<string> imgFileName = new List<string>();
        txbCaption.Text = "";
        if (ImgUpLoad.ImgFleIds != null)
            ImgIds = ImgUpLoad.ImgFleIds;
        if (ViewState["imgIds"] != null)
        {
            List<int> oldids = (List<int>)ViewState["imgIds"];
            ImgIds.AddRange(oldids);
            ImgIds.Sort();
        }
        path = objGetBaseCase.GetImages(ImgIds);
        for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
        {
            ArrayList alst = path[i];
            if (i == 0)
                hImgInsId.Value = alst[0].ToString();

            tb.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(alst[0]), "Figure " + (i + 1).ToString(), alst[2].ToString());
            imgIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(alst[0]));
            imgFileName.Add(alst[2].ToString());
        }
        ViewState["imgIds"] = imgIds;
        ViewState["imgFileName"] = imgFileName;
        DataList1.DataSource = tb;
        DataBind();
        ImgIds.Clear();
        if (DataList1.Items.Count == 1)
        {

            Label lblimgname = (Label)DataList1.Items[0].FindControl("lblimagenumber");
            lblimgname.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "Red");
            lblimgname.Font.Bold = true;
            if (imgIdCapHtbl != null && imgIdCapHtbl.ContainsKey(imgIds[0]))
                txbCaption.Text = imgIdCapHtbl[imgIds[0]].ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imgThumb.ImageUrl="~/Controls/ShowImage.ashx?FileName=" +ImgName;
```

Or I've missed something in your question?

Comment: It depends on when you are binding DataList, if before page load then yes.

Comment: actually i want to show the first image of datalist in image coltrol as image is getting upload in datalist.. for now it is showing when i am clicking on the image. and i am not binging the datalist before page load.

Comment: Share, please, your datalist's binding logic. It is hard to give an aswere. And it is not fair to unmark question as answered, after next question!

Comment: I have edited the qus, and added the databinding code, which i am calling on page load.  ImgUpLoad.AddImgs += delegate { BindImages(); }; Now plz tell me how to show the first image as image get uploaded

Comment: Man, you need huge refactoring up here! All this code is unreadable! ImgUpLoad what is it???? I can't see it in your ascx/aspx code...

Comment: ImgUpLoad is the ascx page name